# Error in wso2esb as well as wso2dss

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.0.0..I have created dataservice to update a record from table..My Dss configuration is as follows

```
 <query id="trial_query" useConfig="default">
      <sql>update muser set username=? where userid=?</sql>
      <param name="username" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="userid" ordinal="2" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
   </query>

 <operation name="trial_op">
      <call-query href="trial_query">
         <with-param name="username" query-param="username"/>
         <with-param name="userid" query-param="userid"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
```

After that i have created a ESB configuration as :

```
 <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="username"
                   expression="//username/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="userid"
                   expression="//userid/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:trail_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <p:username>$1</p:username>
                  <p:userid>$2</p:userid>
               </p:trail_op>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('username')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('userid')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://192.168.1.23:9764/services/Capp_muser_dataservice/trail_op"
                        format="soap12"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
```

and this is also working..Now i wanted to add a sequence mediator in esb and It's configuration is as :

```
 <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="username" expression="get-property('username')" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
   <log>
      <property name="username" value="UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY"></property>
   </log>
   <send></send>
```

I'm sending request with curl command as :

```
  curl -v -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"username":"Harry","userid":"347367127872701992"}' http://youtility-desktop:8282/services/capp1
```

Now, he issue is when i'm adding sequence in send mediator ESB throws an error as :

```
ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:381)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2116)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2022)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1114)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 17 more
```

Still the configuration is working fine with errors too..
I have tried the same code in wso2esb 4.8.0 and wso2dss 3.1.0.Here ESB is working fine but error occurred with wso2dss 3.1.0 . It show error like:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:username
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: Capp_muser_dataservice
Location: /Capp_muser_dataservice.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: trail_op
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:107)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:112)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.executeInOnly(DSOMDataSource.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processSingleRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:127)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:username
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: Capp_muser_dataservice
Location: /Capp_muser_dataservice.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: trail_op
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.extractParams(CallQuery.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:177)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.executeElement(CallQueryGroup.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:548)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:101)
    ... 43 more
```

Why the errors occurred? Is their any problem with soap format during send mediator or  i have to add some properties in esb configuration?What should i do to resolve this issue?Please let me know..

Comment: check with below curl request  


       curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" POST -d '{"username":"Harry","userid":"347367127872701992"}' http://youtility-desktop:8282/services/capp1

Comment: thanks Dakshika..It's working fine upto first sequence with this curl command as well as the curl which i have mentioned in question..But same issue occurred when i'm trying to add second sequence in first sequence..